# How space scientist keeps the track of the stars?

Tags: star

In billions of stars, how space scientist keeps the track of the stars ?

There is a star called [KIC 8462852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KIC_8462852), I saw that picture, star is so small from the earth. It has higher chance to miss that star in the universe.

Comment: Welcome to AstronomySE. Have you taken the [site tour](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tour)? Keshav, you need to show that you've made some effort to find your answer before asking it here. The first item that comes up with the google question "How do scientists keep track of stars?" seems to provide a [good answer](https://www.quora.com/How-do-astronomers-know-which-stars-are-which) for beginners.

Comment: @Chappo That's certainly good advice, but "The first item that comes up with the google question..." isn't really a meaningful concept. Searches in different locations will return very different sets of results, as will searches in different languages. See "After getting beaten up here for not pre-Googling, I can testify that I have indeed searched for 'Gemini BECO' and all I get is a [baby carrier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7skU.jpg)." and other comments associated with [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27339/12102).

Comment: @Chappo here's [another example](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/352131/102305) of a "google first hit." (see first four comments) looking nothing like my google search, due to regional differences.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean to keep track of stars? Do you mean in making sure we don't mistake one for another, follow its proper motion, something else?

Comment: @uhoh good point. I also recognise that language barriers and inexperience in the subject matter can make searches difficult. In any case, my comment provided a link to the answer I found.

Comment: When someone asks a question, how can you tell if the person did not put any effort into finding the answer before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scientists make lists of stars in a catalogue. In the past this would be in a book nowadays it is more likely to be a computer database.

The stars don't move (much) so it is possible to make a list of them by position Modern catalogues are online (see [SINBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) older ones were on paper (see the [1918 Henry Draper catalogue](https://archive.org/stream/henrydrapercata00obsegoog#page/n28/mode/2up))

The Henry Draper catalogue is typical and easier to follow. It is just a table, the first column is the catalogue number (used instead of a "name")  the second column is a cross reference to another database. Then there is information on the location of the star in the sky using the RA and Dec system. Next comes information on the brightness of the star (estimated in two ways). Some letters come next to describe the spectrum (or "colour") of the star and finally some short "remarks", and a "plate number (the number of the photograph that contains an image of the star"

Scientists need to be systematic and careful to avoid missing anything.